# How to find possible reverse duplicates by last date with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, reverse

Been trying to solve this without success... I have a table with data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
    [ID1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ID2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Date] [date] NULL
)

INSERT INTO test VALUES (123,124,'2018-01-01'),
                        (123,125,'2018-01-01'),
                        (125,126,'2018-01-02'),
                        (123,125,'2018-01-02'),
                        (125,123,'2018-01-03'),
                        (126,121,'2018-01-04')
```

Since I only need LAST relation between two pairs, the result should look like:

```
ID1 ID2 Date
123 124 2018-01-01
125 126 2018-01-02
125 123 2018-01-03
126 121 2018-01-04
```

I found many solutions containing only two columns, but none with last date.

Thank you!

Aleš

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you just looking for aggregation?

```
select id1, id2, max(date)
from t
group by id1, id2;
```

Edit:

You seem to want to treat the pair `id1`/`id2` regardless of direction.  If so, use `row_number()`:

```
select id1, id2, date
from (select t.* ,
             row_number() over (partition by (case when id1 < id2 then id1 else id2 end),
                                             (case when id1 < id2 then id2 else id1 end)
                                order by date desc
                               ) as seqnum                                             
      from test t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6fc401/2) is a SQL Fiddle for this solution.

Comment: @AlešJuvančič . . . I saw that once you added the create table statement.